# TimeOut for SFTP Connection

Tags: java, sftp

Iam trying to download a file from a server using sftp. But what ever api i come across is not having a method to set timeout . i have tried using zehon-file-transfer library for this and has seen some pieces of codes also (every where it is same there is no intention to set a timeout). Why we are not defining timeout for sftp ?

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox lets you specify timeouts. It's all about the quality of API development.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the amount of time required to connect to the server or the time required to receive a response from the server? Both are definable in JSCAPE's APIs. Please see [Secure FTP Factory](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-ftp-factory/). Documentation can be located [here](http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/html/index.html?overview16.html)